# Double backslashes when requesting file in Python 3

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making an avoiding game and I'm doing some finishing touches right now where I'm adding a countdown at the beginning of the game. The problem is that when I load in the countdown sound, it does double backslashes and says it can't find it. I've done the same exact same with the game music, and it worked fine. Also, I've seen other posts like this but I've tried every answer and they don't work. I've tried the os join thing, using forward slashes, using the pathlib module, but nothing seems to work. I can open the file just fine. Why does this happen?

Here's the code where it happens, and [the full code with the files](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zLDRiIfC0Zwcd4UJgHHLyovQFkQrDZLA)

```
#play countdown music
countdown1 = os.path.join('Assets', '_count.wav')
countdown2 = pygame.mixer.Sound(countdown1)
countdown2.play(0)
```

Also, how come the music works but this doesn't? This is the music code:

```
#play song
song = pygame.mixer.Sound("Assets\song.wav")
song.play(-1)
```

Comment: You are missing a closing quotation mark. Also, your code relies on `Assets` being in your working directory. Try using an absolute path.

Comment: @KlausD. Where would the quotation marks go?

Comment: Look at the code highlighting above. There is more red than there should be.

Comment: Alright, I've fixed that but it still doesn't work. Here is the exact error message:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Game\Game.pyw", line 498, in <module>
    credits()
  File "C:\Python\Game\Game.pyw", line 489, in credits
    startWarning()
  File "C:\Python\Game\Game.pyw", line 459, in startWarning
    menu()
  File "C:\Python\Game\Game.pyw", line 48, in menu
    game()
  File "C:\Python\Game\Game.pyw", line 127, in game
    countdown2 = pygame.mixer.Sound(countdown1)
pygame.error: Unable to open file 'Assets\\_count.wav'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the file itself. Examining it with a hex dump shows the magic number ID3, indicating the file is actually an mp3. With that being said I was able to get this working by opening the file with a tool called audacity and then exporting the file as a 16-bit WAV file. Audacity is free to download.

1. Change filename from _count.wav to _count.mp3
2. Open with audacity
3. Export as WAV
4. Save as signed 16-bit PCM

Comment: This makes sense because the source I got it from had only mp3. I'll try that and see if it works

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me so much!